# Sheets API Python Error

Tags: python, api, google-sheets

I'm new to installing modules, etc, but believe I've done everything correctly and I'm getting errors. I'm following the instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/python_client_lib#library

Steps:
 1. downloaded Zip of gdata here:
    https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client 
 2. unzipped and placed into my Scripts folder: C:\Python34\Scripts\gdata-python-client-master 
 3. went to cmd, above directory and installed: I did get a bunch of syntax errors (commas, etc), assuming this is why the next steps aren't working...
 4. in python prompt, it says i have module:

[gdata 2.0.18 (c:\python34\lib\site-packages), google-api-python-client 1.4.2 (c:\python34\lib\site-packages), httplib2 0.9.2 (c:\python34\lib\site-packages), oauth2client 1.5.1 (c:\python34\lib\site-packages), pip 6.0.8 (c:\python34\lib\site-packages), pyasn1 0.1.9 (c:\python34\lib\site-packages), pyasn1-modules 0.0.8 (c:\python34\lib\site-packages), requests 2.7.0 (c:\python34\lib\site-packages), rsa 3.2.3 (c:\python34\lib\site-packages), setuptools 12.0.5 (c:\python34\lib\site-packages), simplejson 3.8.1 (c:\python34\lib\site-packages), six 1.10.0 (c:\python34\lib\site-packages), uritemplate 0.6 (c:\python34\lib\site-packages)]

5) But when I try to import gdata i get an error:

```
>>> import gdata.spreadsheet.service
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    import gdata.spreadsheet.service
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gdata\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import atom
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\atom\__init__.py", line 132, in <module>
    CreateClassFromXMLString)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\atom\__init__.py", line 96, in mark_deprecated
    optional_warn_function.func_name = f.func_name
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'func_name'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to unzip to install, use `pip`:

```
http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/
```

You can install the library using `pip install gdata`:

```
https://pythonhosted.org/gdata/installation.html
```

**Update**: `pip` is a good way to install, but this was not actually the problem - the actual root problem was `gdata` compatibility with python2 vs. python3. The fix that worked is described here: https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/issues/29

Specifically running this in the site-packages directory:

```
2to3 -w atom gdata
```

Be warned this will change many files, so having a backup or recovery strategy in place before beginning is strongly advised.

Comment: Thanks, after the install I got a successful message, but when I run the import script I still get the same error

Comment: So if you start up a fresh python interpreter and type `import gdata.spreadsheet.service` you get an error? If so, that tells me it's still not properly installed.

Comment: ya, here's the console log that said succesful:

C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install gdata
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting gdata
  Downloading gdata-2.0.18.tar.gz (2.5MB)
    100% |################################| 2.5MB 165kB/s
Installing collected packages: gdata
  Running setup.py install for gdata
Successfully installed gdata-2.0.18

Comment: Is the unzipped install still in `C:\Python34\Scripts`? If so, you might want to move it out of the way or delete it. I think `import gdata` will look in the current working directory first before checking `site-packages`.

Comment: Same issues... Thanks for trying to help debug... maybe it's a bug on the latest build on github?

Comment: OK, at last I was able to reproduce the error you got (on Python3.4 / Linux). This fixed the issue for me: https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/issues/29 - specifically, I cd'ed into the site-packages directory and ran this: `2to3 -w atom gdata` (lots of output - backing this up first and logging it might be advised if this box is an important one).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95373/discussion-between-davejagoda-and-bramwell2010).